# The regex characters ?, $, |

Tags: regex

I have the following data:

> abc def; ghi.

This regex will match:

```
([a-z0-9A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ ]*)\W (.*)( (\w\.))?
```

This regex will also match

```
([a-z0-9A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ ]*)\W (.*)$
```

I'm still quite new to regex's, but I thought | stood for OR, () grouped and ? stood for 0 or one occurence. So i thought when combining above queries it would still match. However the following will not match:

```
([a-z0-9A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ ]*)\W (.*)( (\w\.))|$
```

What am I doing wrong?

ps.
I am using the following for testing my regex.
http://regexpal.com/

EDIT:
I didn't use the code tag, so a character disappeared

EDIT2:
What I am trying to match is the following, the data will be a name.
So "abc def" is the surname. ghi the salutation (english is not my native language, is that the correct term for words like sir. ?). It's however possible that the first letter of the first name. That's why it should either be the end of the line, or that letter.

The data when there is a first name involved would be:

> abc; def. G.

Comment: I'm not getting a match on the second regex - can you check that?

Comment: Same here. What part of the string are you trying to match on? That part is unclear.

Comment: $ means "the end of the string."  So your last regex doesn't quite make sense.  You have coded "(long-pattern) OR the-end-of-the-string".

Comment: I think if you explained what exactly are you trying to match on both patterns, it would be easier for us to help.

Comment: edited with what I am trying to match.

Comment: I feel like putting in a dummy name would make it immensely more helpful than filling in alphabetical dummy text, e.g., `Van Damme; J.` rather than `abc; def. G.` for a person whose name would then be "def. G. abc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence for the | operator is a little tricky.  It's usually a good idea to explicitly wrap its two operands in parentheses.
Also, be careful about inserting spaces into your regexes.  It looks like you want to match a literal period in the \w. fragment, to match "G."

So I think what you want for the combined expressions is something like

```
((.*)( (\w\.))?)|(.*)$
```

But since ? means 0 or more, as you have learned, this can be rewritten as

```
(.*)( (\w\.))?)$
```

And, to add the rest of the expression back in, we have

```
^[a-z0-9A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ ]*)\W (.*)( (\w\.))?)$
```

And, yes, "salutation" or "greeting" is a good word for "Mr.", "Ms.", "Dr.", etc.

Comment: After I made it correct expression:
([a-z0-9A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ ]*)\W (.*)( (\w\.))?$
It seems to be working.